# Powerquery How to replace contents of one column based on another column

Tags: duplicates, powerquery

I am new to Power Query,
I got stuck when doing the data cleaning, I need help how to detect the duplicates between columns based on the left column and replace the duplicates with a 0 value.

[Column2 have a duplicate in Column3, I need the duplicates in Column3 change to 0 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkeDP.png)

[Column2 have a duplicate in Column3, I need the duplicates in Column3 change to 0 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLeOi.png)

Really appreciate the helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replace"=  Table.ReplaceValue(Source,  each [Column2], each if [Column3]=[Column2] then 0 else [Column3] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column3"})
in #"Replace"
```

[image]